# Loading images into windows phone app from external url

Tags: c#, xaml, image-processing, windows-phone-8

I am trying to load some images from a particular url: `http://www.example.com/Images/`.

I am trying to do the following code which works when I get the images from a local folder :

```
Uri uri = new Uri(filePath + imageName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
try
{
    StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
    return bmp;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

However for the external URL, it is throwing an error on `bmp.SetSource`.

Can you please show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with these streams. Just use:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://www.image.url/address.png"));
```

Comment: I tried that Kamen but did not work, only for local images working.  I think I have to use a web client to download the images

Comment: @Johann I've tried two simple lines - load Bitmap and set it to Image.Source: `BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Celestial_pearl_danio_%28male%29.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)); img.Source = bmp;` - it is working on my emulator, after a while the image is shown.

Comment: @Johann Maybe you should wait until the Bitmap is Opened (use event)?

Comment: i left it for around 5 mins and I am just loading 4 small images. I will try with the web client and see what happens.  Thanks for your help Romasz

Comment: Ok, can you give the actual image address and how you show the graphic?

Comment: @Romasz it worked now!  I am getting my images from a personal cdn, and I did not think that you need the "http://" infront of the cdn.mywebsite.com!  So now its working thanks a lot!